# Can the variables of a parent process be changed by the child process?

Tags: linux, unix, process

I know that threads share the same variables? But what about processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes have separate memory spaces. One process cannot change the memory of another process, and parent/child processes are no exception. A child cannot change a parent's variables, nor a parent its children's.

Processes must use inter-process communication (IPC) mechanisms to talk to each other, such as:

- Pipes
- Signals
- Files
- UNIX sockets
- Network sockets
- Shared memory